# Inheritance of an object through prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, prototypal-inheritance

I know with this question I am demonstrating my confusion with basic concepts of object-based programming, but I am hoping someone can help me with this, as I just can't seem to wrap my head around it:

```
function MagnifyGlass(){

    var magnifiedTiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
    var magnifyingGlass = L.magnifyingGlass({layers: [ magnifiedTiles ]});
    this.magnifyingGlass = magnifyingGlass;

}

MagnifyGlass.prototype.begin=function(){

    $("#map_canvas").mouseenter(function(){
        this.magnifyingGlass.addTo(map);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        map.removeLayer(this.magnifyingGlass);
    });
}

MagnifyGlass.prototype.end=function(){
    map.removeLayer(this.magnifyingGlass);
    $("#map_canvas").unbind();
}

var mg= new MagnifyGlass();

mg.begin();
```

What I want to happen here is that `MagnifyGlass` creates an object that works as a layer in a leaflet map (located in the div `map_canvas`).  Then by calling `.begin` or `.end` I toggle whether that layer appears or not.  I am creating the layer correctly (`magnifyingGlass`) and `.begin` is being called, but somehow the magnifyingGlass object isn't making it to the prototypes and I am pretty sure I have screwed up the this's somehow.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well in your mouseenter event handler you're using this.magnifyingGlass while inside the handler "this" is the function scope not the objects scope. (Same goes for the mouseleave handler)

Comment: Thanks LJ, although unfortunately I still don't understand how to use `this` properly here.  Or is the whole logic of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The answer below describes the proper way, one may also use the "bind" function of functions like "function eventlistener() {}; eventlistener.bind(this);"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue. Here's a fix:

```
MagnifyGlass.prototype.begin=function(){
    var self = this;
    $("#map_canvas").mouseenter(function(){
        self.magnifyingGlass.addTo(map);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        map.removeLayer(self.magnifyingGlass);
    });
}
```

Exactly what LJ_1102 said.